# Nested table products query mysql

Tags: mysql, database, performance, nested

I have the following database structure and, even though my database is not so big, I want to adopt a single query method for displaying the products in any given node or leaf.
The current database has products associated to leafs as well to nodes that contain other children (please see products 3 and 4).
What I would like to list is all products that belong to nodes and children contained by $_GET['node'], where node can be the root, the leaf or any other children parent.

```
+---------+-----+-----+---------+
| tree_id | lft | rgt |  name   |
+---------+-----+-----+---------+
|       1 |   1 | 138 | TV's    |
|       2 |   2 |  91 | Phones  |
|       3 |   3 |  26 | Samsung |
|       4 |   4 |  10 | Used    |
|       5 |  11 |  25 | New     |
|       6 |  27 |  45 | Apple   |
|       7 |  46 |  90 | Philips |
|       8 |  47 |  51 | Touch   |
|       9 |  52 |  89 | Key     |
|         |     |     |         |
+---------+-----+-----+---------+

+------------+-------------+-------+
| product_id |    Name     | make  |
+------------+-------------+-------+
|          1 | Touch Easy  | 4466  |
|          2 | Eagle Eye   | 5523  |
|          3 | Super Phone | 7Utt  |
|          4 | Crazy Touch | Utiir |
+------------+-------------+-------+

+------------+--------+
| product_id | cat_id |
+------------+--------+
|          1 |      5 |
|          2 |      8 |
|          3 |      2 |
|          4 |      3 |
+------------+--------+
```

I am not so much familiarized with complex queries so, what i do to get all the products inside a node (2) is:

```
   $node = SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = 2 
    $products = SELECT products_categories.id 
FROM `products_categories`, `categories` 
WHERE `categories`.`left` > ".$node['left']." 
AND `categories`.`right` < ".$node['right']." 
AND `products_categories`.`cat_id` = `categories`.`id` 

    foreach($products as $product){

    $prod = new Product($prod['id'])


    }
```

As you can see, I am executing three queries (one inside the class) which, I am sure, it is not the best approach.

Comment: list your expected result and what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This nested set model is a more complex than the usual adjacent model especially in the data manipulation part but quite fast for selection.

Anyway with a simple google search you may find open source classes that can help you achieve your tasks with ease.

Such one is: https://github.com/riquito/Baobab

The search keywords I used are: `github nested set model php mysql`

Edit:

For your specific case a query such as this might work:

```
SET @cid := 2;
SET @lft := (SELECT `lft` FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = @cid);
SET @rgt := (SELECT `rgt` FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = @cid);

SELECT `pc`.`productID`
  FROM `products_categories` `pc`
    LEFT JOIN `categories` `c` ON `c`.`id` = `pc`.`categoryID`
  WHERE `c`.`lft` > @lft
    AND `c`.`rgt` < @rgt
;
```